# How to do Control+Backspace on standard USB Keyboard?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, macos

At work we use Macbooks, so I am trying to adapt :)

I am using to many things, one of them is doing Ctrl+Delete in Mac OSX (In IntelliJ IDEA).

What I expect to happen, that works in Windows and on another external keyboard (Mac one!) is that when you press ctrl+delete, the left most word is deleted.

This does not happen on Mac, I could not find any other key combination to do this.
I need to functionality to quickly move around my code, please help.
My Mac version is 10.12.5

Comment: Try Ctrl-Fn-Backspace  - Delete is Fn-Backspace

Comment: Not helping, it is still deleting only one character and not the whole word.

Comment: Besides I only have happen to have Fn function key on the keyboard because it is a Mechanical Keyboard, and the Fn is used to control alternative functions like lighting, and media such as mute etc (which seem to be working, I just tested Fn+F1 and it mutes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyboard shortcut to delete the word to the left of the insertion point is, on a Mac keyboard:

<kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd>
[image]
[image]

On a Windows keyboard use:
<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd>
[image]

I use both Windows and macOS on a regular basis and noticed that some keyboard shortcuts that use <kbd>Control</kbd> in Windows work with <kbd>Option</kbd> in macOS, for example:

Delete the word to the left/right of the insertion point:

- Windows: <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd> / <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd>
- macOS:  <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd> / <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>delete⌦</kbd>

[On keyboards that don't have <kbd>delete⌦</kbd> (Forward Delete) use <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd> instead.]

Move the insertion point to the beginning/end of the previous word:

- Windows: <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> / <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>
- macOS:  <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> / <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>

Extend text selection to the beginning/end of the current word:

- Windows: <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> / <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>
- macOS:  <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> / <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>

Please refer to https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236 for a complete list of keyboard shortcuts (scroll down to the Document shortcuts section for the juicy stuff).

Comment: Thank you! Alt-Backspace works, strange that it didn't work before.. maybe it started after a restart today. Anyway great solution, very well illustrated! :)

Comment: I figured out sometimes it stops working after I disconnect the keyboard and everything, go to some meeting, then come back.

Comment: Side note - when using a Windows keyboard this no longer works in OSX Sierra

Answer (score -1):

`Shift+Option+Backspace` should do it!

Comment: Don't want to split hairs here, but there is no Backspace key on a Mac keyboard, at least not by that name: Apple calls that key simply "Delete". The Windows Delete key is called "Forward Delete". As for the keyboard shortcut you suggest, the Shift key is not necessary, Option+Delete works too.

Comment: @jaume - there's a separate backspace key on full sized keyboards, just not on laptops. It's only labelled Delete on the US keyboard.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for pointing that out, my wok MBP has a German keyboard layout and the key is indeed not labeled Delete (the key has simply an arrow pointing to the left, very similar to the key on a Windows keyboard). My point was that Apple calls that key "Delete" (even if not labeled as such). not "Backspace". Of course, in other languages Apple calls the Delete key differently and there may be some overlapping with the name Windows uses (as it is the case in German).

Comment: I *think* I've always called that one Backspace & I have a vague recollection that back in the 90's it actually said that.... this is bearing in mind that my current [Apple full-size] keyboard actually labels the Opt key as Alt... so who knows ;)) I sneaked a picture of the brand new full-size kbd from the Apple Store... they gave up altogether with backspace/delete & both now just have arrows [but Opt is back!] -https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6LYR.jpg